# Changing CSS Styles Based On Varying Time Increments

Tags: javascript, css

I haven’t started this yet… But I’d like to get some input on this because I am just beginning with coding and I thought getting some different ideas before I start tomorrow will be valuable…

I’m trying to make a list of topics that cycle in colour (active/inactive) one by one from top to bottom based off of varying time data.

How would you go about this?

The time data is stored in a Firebase collection with each doc containing a topic and the time data. The topics are being automatically inserted into the page using a forEach function - into ls tags. I am not asking for help with the Firebase/Firestore side of things.. Just the JavaScript.

I’m using JavaScript to do all the work atm and are not too keen on using anything else because I’m not familiar with coding enough to take on a new language atm.

My thinking is having the JavaScript cycle through the time data one by one and when each time has elapsed it changes the CSS class of each ls tag from active to inactive and vice versa. But I’m not sure how to do the JavaScript time based cycling part. Changing the CSS I’m able to do

What are your thoughts? How would you do this and do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Have you looked at [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)?

Comment: can you clarify what the relationship between time data and colour is meant to be? is it supposed to blink on and off in real time? is it supposed to be sorted by time and then just listed in a striped pattern? is the colour supposed to represent something about the time (e.g. whether weekday or weekend, morning or evening etc..)?

Comment: The time data varies and will be in array like form that is cycled through from top to bottom. The list will also cycle from top to bottom with varying times one by one. So basically list item no1 will go green for 15 seconds (this is from the data) then go black then list item no 2 goes green for 30 seconds (this is from the data)and 1 will go black and so on down the list descending

Comment: I have looked into setTimeout need to look into it more. I’m more concerned about the cycling through the data tho

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change if than you can do something like this.

```js
var time = 5000; //time from database
setTimeout(() => {
  //changeColor function
  console.log("Color changed");
}, time) //time in milliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks useful. Not doing any work today but I’ll give it a try tomorrow.